# How to pass superclass object to restful service (jersey)

Tags: web-services, jersey, restful-architecture

I have two POJOs

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class PojoBase {
 }

 @XmlRootElement
 public class PojoRequest extends PojoBase {

 private String strTemplate;

 public void setTemplate(String strTemplate) {
    this.strTemplate = strTemplate;
 }

 public String getTemplate() {
    return strTemplate;
 }

 }

 @XmlRootElement
 public class PojoResponse extends PojoBase {

private String strName;

public void setName(String strName) {
    this.strName = strName;
}

public String getName() {
    return strName;
}

}
```

I have service which accepts the base class and returns the base class as response.

```
@POST
@Path("/start")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PojoBase registerNumber(JAXBElement<PojoBase> theRequest) {
        //does some work with theRequest.

        //here the theRequest object doesn't has pojoRequest data.
        PojoResponse pojoResponse = new PojoResponse();
        pojoResponse.setName("Sample");
        return pojoResponse;
    }
```

From client I am sending pojo base object but not sure why Restful doesn't get actual theRequest object.

Here is the client code:

```
 public class HttpClient {
    static String _strServiceURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/middleware/rest/service/start";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PojoRequest pojoRequest = new PojoRequest();
        pojoRequest.setTemplate("Somedata");

        PojoBase response = getResponse(pojoRequest);
        PojoResponse pojoresponse = (PojoResponse) response;
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    private static PojoBase getResponse(PojoBase request) {
         try {
             Client client = Client.create();
             WebResource webResource = client.resource(_strServiceURL);
             ClientResponse response = webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
             System.out.println(response.getStatus()); 
             if(response.getStatus() == 200){
                   PojoBase response =  response.getEntity(PojoBase.class);
                   return response;
             }      
          } catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          return null;
      }
```

}

Can you please tell me how to get the PojoRequest at Service end?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass a superclass to jersey like this. I believe, though I may be wrong, that as `registerNumber()` has a parameter `JAXBElement<PojoBase>`  it will do something like:

1. instantiate a PojoBase
2. do reflection on `PojoBase` (which has no properties), therefore nothing to set.
3. call `registerNumber()` with the practically empty `PojoBase` object

So why not try changing the signature to:

```
public PojoBase registerNumber(JAXBElement< PojoRequest > theRequest)
```

or even (with com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature = true):

```
public PojoBase registerNumber(PojoRequest theRequest)
```

Comment: paultth and user2788006 I am looking for a way to send and recieve object in restful jersey service. If i put JAXBElement myPojoClassReference as method parameter and consumes and produces are kept same . Will it work as mentioned above? I am trying to convert my soap service to restful.

Comment: @Yashu If I were you I would create a question containing more details about what you're trying to do, and put a link to it in these comments so we can try to help? Also others will then see it and maybe you will get a good answer

Comment: I was just reading concepts of restfull web service came here wondering if i can recieve a java object as an argument into my web service method. For example:-
Consider PojoBase class above which i want to recieve . Will something like this work as a server side method. public PojoBase registerNumber(JAXBElement<PojoBase> theRequest) { } And then write a client side code as same written above? Will that do?

Comment: Oh ok yeah that sounds entirely possible. I believe Jersey 2 has very good client side support, helping to match code up in the way you describe